# OutOfMemoryError андроид при выводе изоброжение в Imagview

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {



            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            Log.d("log", String.format("bitmap size = %sx%s, byteCount = %s",
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    (int) (bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024)));
                    logMemory();

            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView

                galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(filePath);
                String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            bitmap,
                            bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                            0,
                            bitmap.getHeight(),
                            bitmap.getHeight()
                    );
                    bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);


                }else{

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            bitmap,
                            0,
                            bitmap.getHeight() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                            bitmap.getWidth(),
                            bitmap.getWidth()
                    );
                    bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);

                }



            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           // uploadImage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Где-то в процессе создания битмапа кончается память. Покажите код, который вызывает это исключение.

Comment: не загружать большие картинки\не загружать картинки вообще\выгружать неиспользуемые картинки перед загрузкой новых. Ответ на ваш вопрос очевиден - у вас закончилась память.

Comment: добавил посмотрите пожалуйста